# Pandas pivot multiple columns, indexes, and values

Tags: pandas, pivot

I have the following dataset

|  | resulted_by | follow_up_result | follow_up_number | # | % |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | User 1 | good | 1 | 30 | 30 |
| 1 | User 2 | good | 2 | 65 | 65 |
| 2 | User 3 | bad | 3 | 5 | 0.05 |

I want to Pivot:

- `follow up result` and `resulted by` as indexes
- `follow up number` as a column
- `#` and `%` as values

```py
pivot = df.head(3).pivot(columns=['follow_up_number'], values=["#", '%'], index=['follow_up_result', 'resulted_by'])
```

[image]

However, I want the follow up number to be above the values, here is how I achieved that:

```py
pivot = df.head(3).pivot(columns=['follow_up_result', 'resulted_by'], values=["#", '%'], index=['follow_up_number'])
pivot = pivot.stack(level=0).T
```

Notice how I switch `columns` and `indexes`.

[image]

I want the column names to be at the same level as the values.

Is there a way to do that?

Is there a better way to achieve what I need without switching between `columns` and `indexes`?

Code Snippet:

https://onecompiler.com/python/3y5gzm7hu

Comment: I think you just want `.swaplevel(0, 1, axis='columns')` to switch the order of the column levels.

Comment: @creanion that works partially. I need # and % to be under the same follow up number, if that makes sense. `swaplevel` splits them up.

Comment: `follow_up_result` and `resulted_by` are not column names(colum headers), there are index level names.  Hence the appear differently when displayin this dataframe.

Comment: It is not total clear what your desired result should look like  it seems that you are confusing column headers with index label names.

Comment: I see - we could instead say that - swaplevel keeps columns in place - location unchanged - but you want to re-sort them with `.swaplevel(0, 1, axis='columns').sort_index(axis='columns')`  so that you have the 1s, 2s, 3s in that order.
It's clear, if you imagine the multilevel columns as tuples - [(1, "#"), (1, "%"), ...] and so on.

Comment: @creanion yes! That solved the second question of not needing to switch between `index` and `columns`, thank you! Now, is there a way to get the `follow_up_result` and `resulted_by` to be at the same level as the values so that I don't have those empty spaces in the table? I updated the code snippet, just run it and you will see what I mean. cc/ @Scott Boston

Comment: @ScottBoston and execute the code in the code snippet, I think you will better understand what I'm looking for, thanks!

Comment: @RafaelGarcia Follow_up_number is the label for multiIndex column header level=0, that blank line below that is the label for column header level=1.   Moving 'follow_up_results' and 'result_by' up to the blank line wouldn't be the correct way to display this column header.     What we can do is to flatten the multi_index column header then reset_index.

Comment: @ScottBoston that makes sense. I'm satisfied with the current solution. Thank you.

Comment: @creanion I can mark your answer as correct if you post it